# How to remove date grouping headers in the message list in the Outlook app?

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, office365

My company uses Office 365, and I'd like to remove the date grouping (headers) in the list of e-mail messages in Outlook, because they take up a lot of room.

I was able to do that on the web interface (https://outlook.office365.com/mail/) via the option
*Settings -> View all Outlook settings -> Mail -> Layout -> Don't show date headers in the message list*.

However, I want to do that on the app (Outlook, Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise, Version 2108 on a Windows 10 machine) and this option is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook you can customize the view by going to *View ribbon -> View settings -> Group By...*.

There you can uncheck the *Automatically group according to arrangement* and set which field you want to group your message by instead in the *Group items by* dropdown (none is an option).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way:

*View -> Arrangement -> the tiny button which looks like a |> rotated by 90° and whose tooltip says More -> uncheck Show in Groups*

This needs to be done manually for every folder; it's not possible to select multiple folders and change this setting as once. Very annoying, but expected given it's a Microsoft software.